# How to locate the element "<a data-item-id="com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:agile-velocity-chart"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

How to locate the following element:

```html
<a data-item-id="com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:agile-velocity-chart" href="/jira/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?projectKey=RSWM&amp;rapidView=3254&amp;view=reporting&amp;chart=velocityChart" tabindex="-1">Velocity Chart</a>
```

Comment: <a data-item-id="com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:agile-velocity-chart" href="/jira/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?projectKey=RSWM&amp;rapidView=3254&amp;view=reporting&amp;chart=velocityChart" tabindex="-1">Velocity Chart</a>

Comment: this is the actual html code for element

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: It's important to have a bit more context. Ideally, when finding elements for automated testing, you want to search for something that's not likely to change.

Comment: Please specify which exact element or attribute you need to get through your xpath.
Much better is also to post a full well-formed xml, not just one tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  a[href^='/jira/secure/RapidBoard'][data-item-id$='agile-velocity-chart']
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  //a[starts-with(@href, '/jira/secure/RapidBoard') and contains(@data-item-id, 'agile-velocity-chart')][text()='Velocity Chart']
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing which looks non-dynamic and human-readable is link text so the relevant XPath expression would be:

```
//a[text()='Velocity Chart']
```

you might also want to match the element using `chart=velocityChart` bit, if this is the case you can look up `href` attribute using XPath [`contains()` function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) like:

```
//a[contains(@href,'velocityChart')]
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath in Selenium WebDriver: Complete Tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)